# Android Google maps Api doesn't uncluster while zoom in

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, markerclusterer

I created `Custom Cluster Render` extending `DefaultClusterRenderer<T>`, while using `Google Maps Api` and `android maps utils`. According to the following guide 
 https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java

When I have more then too many `markers`in the same area, they cluster into the one. But the don't separate onto `markers` while  zooming, and I can see

http://cs627121.vk.me/v627121202/51eb5/rY9f4p8ivos.jpg

Here's some code:

```
 public PlaceRender(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyCluster> clusterManager) {
    super(context, map, clusterManager);
    mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
    imageView = new ImageView(context);
    mClusterImageView = new ImageView(context);
    mIconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);
    this.context = context;
    this.map = map;
    this.myClusterManager = clusterManager;
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyCluster cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(cluster, markerOptions);
    markerOptions.title(cluster.name).snippet(cluster.snippet);
    markerOptions.infoWindowAnchor(0.5f, 0.0f);


}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyCluster> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions);
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
    // Always render clusters.
    return cluster.getSize() > 1;
}

@Override
protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<MyCluster> cluster, Marker marker){
    super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
}


@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyCluster geo, Marker marker) {
    super.onClusterItemRendered(geo, marker);
    loadIconFromApi(geo, marker);
}


public void addItems(List<MyCluster> clusters, Context context, GoogleMap map) {
    myClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(context, map);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++) {
        myClusterManager.addItem(clusters.get(i));
        myClusterManager.setRenderer(new PlaceRender(context, map, myClusterManager));

    }
    myClusterManager.cluster();

}

//
private void loadIconFromApi(MyCluster geo, Marker marker) {
    PicassoMarker markers = new PicassoMarker(marker, mIconGenerator, imageView);
    geo.setPicassoMarker(markers);
    Picasso.with(context).load(geo.image).into(markers);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    return true;
}
```

If I use `15x camera zoom`, so I can see every marker, and then `zoom out` it, my markers won't merge into the one `cluster`.

What did I missed?

Comment: Please clarify as it is unclear what is the problem. Is it that markers do not cluster when you zoom out or they do not stop clustering when you zoom in to them? Or both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I  needed  to add this function and call it in `onCameraChange`

```
public void updateUI(List<MyCluster> clusters) {
        myClusterManager.clearItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++) {
            myClusterManager.addItem(clusters.get(i));
         //   myClusterManager.setRenderer(new PlaceRender(context, map, myClusterManager));

    }
    myClusterManager.onCameraChange(map.getCameraPosition());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `shouldRenderAsCluster()` is always clustering due to the condition you set.

```
cluster.getSize() > 1;
```

You can check out a similar SO post over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159284/map-clustering-max-zoom-markers-still-clustered?rq=1)

Also, try to check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947100/google-maps-cluster-item-marker-icon-with-picasso) post. Figured that you are using **PicassoMarker** library which might have affected your cluster rendering too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. if I return `false` in `shouldRenderAsCluster()` markers don't cluster. But, how can I reach `clustering` and `unclustering` while  zooming using `Picasso`?

Answer (score 0):

For me,  I did not set CameraIdleListener with the map object.
Started to work and show individual pins when I zoomed in after setting CameraIdleListener as well as MarkerClickListener.
[followed the implementation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

```
myClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(context, map);

// Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
// manager.
map.setOnCameraIdleListener(myClusterManager);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(myClusterManager);
```